# What does it mean for a Service to be of type NodePort, and have both port and targetPort specified?

Tags: kubernetes

I am becoming more familiar with Kubernetes by the day, but am still at a basic level.  I am also not a networking guy.

I am staring at the following snippet of a Service definition, and I can't form the right picture in my mind of what is being declared:

```
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 27018
    targetPort: 27017
    protocol: TCP
```

Referencing the [ServicePort documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/resources-reference/v1.5/#serviceport-v1), which reads in part:

```
nodePort     The port on each node on which this service is exposed when type=NodePort or LoadBalancer. Usually
integer      assigned by the system. If specified, it will be allocated to the service if unused or else creation of the
             service will fail. Default is to auto-allocate a port if the ServiceType of this Service requires one. More info: 
             http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/services#type--nodeport

port         The port that will be exposed by this service.
integer

targetPort   Number or name of the port to access on the pods targeted by the service. Number must be in the range 1
IntOrString  to 65535. Name must be an IANA_SVC_NAME. If this is a string, it will be looked up as a named port in the
             target Pod's container ports. If this is not specified, the value of the 'port' field is used (an identity map).
             This field is ignored for services with clusterIP=None, and should be omitted or set equal to the 'port' field.
             More info: http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/services#defining-a-service
```

My understanding is that the port that a client outside of the cluster will "see" will be the dynamically assigned one in the range of `30000`-`32767`, as defined [in the documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/services/#type-nodeport).  This will, using some black magic that I do not yet understand, flow to the `targetPort` on a given node (`27017` in this case).

So what is the `port` used for here?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

`nodePort` is the port that a client outside of the cluster will "see". `nodePort` is opened on every node in your cluster via [kube-proxy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/services/#type-nodeport). With iptables magic Kubernetes (k8s) then routes traffic from that port to a matching service pod (even if that pod is running on a completely different node).

`port` is the port your service listens on inside the cluster. Let's take this example:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-service
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 8080
    targetPort: 8070
    nodePort: 31222
    protocol: TCP 
  selector:
    component: my-service-app
```

From inside my k8s cluster this service will be reachable via `my-service.default.svc.cluster.local:8080` (service to service communication inside your cluster) and any request reaching there is forwarded to a running pod on `targetPort` 8070.

`tagetPort` is also by default the same value as `port` if not specified otherwise.

Comment: Thank you.  So `nodePort` is _not_ a port that the Service listens on?  It is instead a port that is opened on Nodes hosting the Pods that the Service fronts?

Comment: `nodePort` is unique, so 2 different services cannot have the same `nodePort` assigned. Once declared, the k8s master reserves that `nodePort` for that service. `nodePort` is then opened on **EVERY** node (master and worker) - also the nodes that do not run a pod of that service - [k8s iptables](https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/services/#virtual-ips-and-service-proxies) magic takes care of the routing. That way you can make your service request from outside your k8s cluster to any node on `nodePort` without worrying whether a pod is scheduled there or not.

Comment: From the #kubernetes-users Slack channel: "the `nodePort` routes to the service, which in turn routes to the pod / if you hit the service directly then the `nodePort` step is skipped / the 'magical routing' is handled by `kube-proxy`".  This led me to say (using invented notation): "`nodePort` -> `port` -> `targetPort`, not `nodePort` -> `targetPort` && `port` -> `targetPort`".

Comment: @LairdNelson I like that port chain explanation. I wasn't entirely sure if kube-proxy always routes to the service `port` first (coming from `nodePort`) or if in some cases it skips this step and goes directly `nodePort` -> `targetPort`. Thank you for that clarification!

Comment: In your example:

any.host.in.the.cluster:31222 => service.listening:8080 => one.of.the.pods.listening:8070

more info in this scenario:https://www.katacoda.com/courses/kubernetes/networking-introduction

Answer (score 8):

To explain better the concept, I visualize Service's NodePort concept.

[image: NodePort Service]

As [@fishi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41963878/2586315) mentioned in his answer NodePort allows exposing k8s host port(aka `nodePort`) to the external clients. A client can directly access `nodePort` and k8s forwards a traffic to the necessary port.

K8s reserves a `nodePort` on all its nodes. All nodes that running the Service's pods have this port open.

Pods can be accessed not only through internal cluster IP but also through node's IP and reserved port aka `HOST_IP:NODE_PORT` pair.

Comment: I believe the image is misguiding. If, CURL http://10.0.2.15:30230 is an external call, it should point to the cloud NodePort and that one does the request follow to the pod. That would mean that the cloud part should have Node IP: 10.0.2.15 and NodePort: 30230. And additionally, the "Pod: CURL" pod should be shown with a request directly to the "Pod: Nginx" pod. You can also have "Pod: CURL" pod have a request to the Node cloud part, but I don't think you wanted to depict that.

Comment: In this diagram, I think 'hostPort' is the `nodePort`, and 'Node Port' is the `port`.

Comment: This is confusing! I guess