# Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))

Tags: python, api, kubernetes, deployment, google-cloud-platform

I have deployed an API on Google Kubernetes Engine .Now I am trying to get response from the deployed Api .But It is giving me Following Error

Error On Curl:

> "curl: (7) Failed to connect to 35.202.134.213 port 80: Connection
>   refused"

Error On Python Client :

> ""HTTPConnectionPool(host='35.221.125.222', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /predict/ (Caused by NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))""

Can anybody guide me what is problem?

Comment: check your port definition https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49981601/difference-between-targetport-and-port-in-kubernetes-service-definition

Comment: I have not get answer from above given link by you.can you elaborate for me