# Getting net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED while trying to connect to backend service

Tags: node.js, kubernetes

```js
POST https://localhost:3008/v1/login net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

I had a setup to deploy a React app and a nodejs server with their services.  https://github.com/Binomi0/gbpd/tree/develop/pods/gbpd

I can start all without errors but:
If runs `kubectl exec -it "gbpd-front-xxxxx" -- /bin/bash` and then `curl https://gbpd-api` **No answer**
If runs `kubectl exec -it "gbpd-front-xxxxx" -- /bin/bash` and then `curl gbpd-api` **No answer**
If runs `kubectl exec -it "gbpd-front-xxxxx" -- /bin/bash` and then `curl https://gbpd-api:3008` **Gets this answer**:

```
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
 of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default
 bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
 using the --cacert option.
If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
 the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
 problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
 not match the domain name in the URL).
If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
 the -k (or --insecure) option.
```

As far as I know, with lastone it gets a response so why getting the title error in web?

---

### What manage to get working with docker-compose file

I got a `docker-compose` file https://github.com/Binomi0/gbpd/blob/develop/docker-compose.yml that runs ok.

```yaml
...
args:
  REACT_APP_API_URL: https://localhost:3008
```

Then I can run `docker-compose up` and get everything connecting OK.

What I can see:

Project needs to be built with then ENV var set before build process?.
Then if i set `environment: - foo=bar` it goes to container but the app misses it. So we can't use environment vars in this kind of setup?
When runs `docker-compose up` we are building the image and passing as `args` to `Dockerfile` ARG and setting the right ENV vars before building.

```
#Dockerfile

FROM node:12

WORKDIR /usr/src/app/front

ARG REACT_APP_API_URL
RUN echo $REACT_APP_API_URL

ENV REACT_APP_API_URL=$REACT_APP_API_URL

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

RUN npm run build

RUN npm install -g serve

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["serve", "-s", "build", "-l", "3000"]
```

---

I'm lost in how to connect front to back with this setup, so will be very appreciated if someone can show some light on it. 
Why can't connect using localhost like in development or deploying with compose?
Why even creating build passing `gbpd-api` it gets refused?

I can give more feedback if needed.
Thx in advance!!

Comment: Your containerPort is "http", should be a number, more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49981601). What is your infrastructure? I don't understand why you want to use https when you didn't specify the certificates, www server, loadbalancer . Maybe this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@lukaszwolnik/nodejs-app-with-database-over-ssl-on-kubernetes-b0f0ad185e62) could help your understand more how it works. You could try `use the -k (or --insecure) option with curl` to check if it actually works without certs or you have more errors. I would start with fixing those services.

Comment: I'm on a MacOs machine running Docker Desktop.  I can run everything with docker just with `docker-compose up`. So I don't know why docker YES, k8s NOT. Just wondering whats happening here. Why you said I need a certs while docker doesn't?

Comment: Because docker is not k8s, same as k8s is not docker. Worth to read about it, for example [here](https://www.appdynamics.com/blog/product/migrating-from-docker-compose-to-kubernetes/). I said that because that what your error says, `curl: (60) SSL certificate problem`. Maybe it's worth to try [kompose](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/translate-compose-kubernetes/), In just a few steps, it will take you from Docker Compose to Kubernetes yamls, maybe there are some mistakes in your yamls and that's why it's not working.

Comment: @jt97 Thx a lot! just starting with k8s, looks like i'm confused with concerns so will read your recommendations.