# Kubernetes Access External IP via Port and not NodePort

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-service

I'm new to Kubernetes and Helm Charts and was looking to find an answer to my question here.

When I run `kubectl get all` and look under services, I get something like:

```
NAME             TYPE           CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP      PORT(S)                        AGE
service/leader   LoadBalancer   10.3.245.137   104.198.205.71   80:30125/TCP, 8888:30927/TCP   54s
```

My services are configured in my Helm Chart as:

```
ports:
  name: api
  port: 80
  targetPort: 8888 

  name: api2
  port: 8888
  targetPort: 8888
```

When I run `kubectl describe svc leader`, I get:

```
Type:        LoadBalancer
Port:        api 80/TCP
TargetPort:  8888/TCP 
NodePort:    api 30125/TCP
EndPoints:   <some IP>:8888
Port:        api 8888/TCP
TargetPort:  8888/TCP 
NodePort:    api 30927/TCP
EndPoints:   <some IP>:8888
```

I always thought that `NodePort` is the port that exposes my cluster externally, and Port would be the port exposed on the service internally which routes to `TargetPorts` on the Pods. I got this understanding from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49981601/difference-between-targetport-and-port-in-kubernetes-service-definition).

However, it seems I can open up `104.198.205.71:80` or `104.198.205.71:8888`, but I can't for `104.198.205.71:30125` or `104.198.205.71:30927`. My expectation is I should be able to access 104.198.205.71 through the `NodePorts`, and not through the Ports. Is my understanding incorrect?

Comment: to access through nodePort, you need to use node external IP. `kubectl get node -owide`   should give you theIP of the node.

Comment: I see. Does it make sense that I have the option to access through Ports though? I thought Ports were only internally exposed in the cluster, and I would assume something like <External IP>:80 would fail if I tried to do so in my browser.

Comment: in your **node**(not container) where you think port `80` is working. check `sudo netstat -tulnp |grep-w 80`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access your application via NodePort, then you need to hit your node ip and the nodeport which you have been assigned.

```
kubectl get node -owide
```

The above command will give your node ip address, which you can use to access the app via NodePort and yes external Ip : 80 will fail as the port is for the container internally and not for outside access.

Comment: hey thanks for responding! For some reason though, external IP:80 seems to be working for me, and I was wondering why that might be the case.

Answer (score 1):

Furthermore, to read more about accessing your resources from outside of your cluster using Publishing Services (NodePort is also mentioned there)  you can refer to [the official documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#publishing-services-service-types).