# Google Compute kubernetes only can be access when nodePort on NodePort service is 80

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, docker-compose, flannel

Somehow, I am trying to start a kubernetes project on Google Compute (not GKE). After all installation (read docker-ce, kubelet, kubeadm) I create a Service and a Deployment inside as follows :

```
apiVersion : v1
kind : Service
metadata:
  name: client-node-port
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 90
    targetPort: 80
    nodePort: 31515
  selector:
    component: web
```

It was working until I change the targetPort inside service to any port beside 80 (along with the Deployment containerPort).

I already tried enabling the port on the instance `firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=(any port beside 80)/tcp`

Beside that I also already enable the firewall rule in google [Google Firewall Setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NG7Ei.png)

Is there anything that I missed ? Why I can only access the NodePort when nodePort setting in the service is 80 ?

Thanks

PS : If it is relevant, I am using flannel network

Answer (score 0):

May I know why you are trying to change `targetPort` ?

`TargetPort`is the port on the POD where the service is running.

`Nodeport`is the port on which the service can be accessed from external users by  nodeip:nodeport.

`Port`: the same as Nodeport but can be used by cluster users using clusterip:port.

Again, in your case port 80 represents the service is actually running on port 80.

You should change `targetPort`in case you will set the service in the pod that is running on a different port.

Review [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41963433/what-does-it-mean-for-a-service-to-be-of-type-nodeport-and-have-both-port-and-t?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) for more details.

Comment: I supposed to be able to change `targetPod` to any port that I want, no ? I understand about the targetPort , nodePort, and port that you explained, just GCE doesnt allow to change port, I mean there is some mechanism to block other port inside